# SQL database design feedback

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a simple database that I am designing for my web application. The basic premise is the website displays a series of statements that a user reads, clicks "I agree etc" and submits a form with their personal details and the statements Id's they agreed to. Occasionally the statement text may change and we want to keep track of this through versioning. We don't want to lose the history of the statement text for auditing as we want to be able to pull the records at a later time to see what each user agreed to. I also want to make sure each statement is versioned so that when I query the database for records to display in my application I only want to display the most current iteration.

Here are the tables I have

**Form**

- FormID
- FormName
- FormText
- VersionNumber
- Active
- CreateDate
- CreateUser

**User**

- UserID
- Firstname
- Lastname
- CreateDate
- CreateUser

**UserForm**

- UserID
- FormID
- CreateDate
- CreateUser

The UserForm table can have many forms to each user but I need to structure the database is such a way to know which version of the form they agreed to. Currently the way I have it is I would create a new record in the Form table with a different Version number and mark it as Active with the new text. I then would mark the old record as Inactive and only display the active forms on my website. What other way can I do this?

Comment: the userform can be a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design seems pretty solid to me. If you're concerned about the possibility of having multiple active versions of the form at the same time you can add a constraint to the table which will prevent that like this (lets assume that `FormID` is your primary, surrogate key, and that `FormCode` is the consistent identifier that you use for a form across all different versions of it):

```
Create Unique Index ux_FormCode_Active On Form (FormCode) Where Active = 'Active';
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with the design is that you could end up with multiple versions of the same form marked as Active - it is hard to constrain the database to guarantee this didn't happen.

One way to solve this would be to add a FormType table, with a ActiveFormId showing which FormId was the current one for each type. You would still link Users to Forms as you are.